# How to find out if the current date in rails is between a predefined date range (without the year)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have the following code in a helper within rails, which allows me to set a start date and end date and return true based on whether the current date is between the predefined range. My problem is with this code it'll only work for the current year, however I want to change it so it'll return true if the date is within the range, ignoring the year.

```
def is_christmas?
  start_date = Date.parse('01-12-2016')
  end_date = Date.parse('25-12-2016')
  today = Date.today
  today.between?(start_date, end_date)
end
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Check whether the month is December and the day is in the range `1..25`.  Which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: I currently know how to check whether the date is a specific date i.e. 1-12-2016, but unsure of how to eliminate the year and only check for the day/month

Comment: to clarify - you effectively want to ignore year so that you can test if for example '14-12' falls between '01-12' and '25-12' ? What about when start_date is '01-12-2016' and end_date is '25-01-2017' - what are you expecting as a result when you test if a date falls between '01-12' and '25-01'?

Comment: I'll need the year to change every year, something along the lines of `Date.parse('01-11-(Date.currentyear)')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> unsure of how to eliminate the year and only check for the day/month

To check for the [`day`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-day):

```
date.day.between?(1, 25)
```

To check for the [`month`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-month):

```
date.month == 12
```

And to check for both:

```
date.month == 12 && date.day.between?(1, 25)
```

Wrapped in a method:

```
def is_christmas?(date = Date.today)
  date.month == 12 && date.day.between?(1, 25)
end
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Tiny suggestion: swap the tests round in #is_christmas? because the month test is more likely to be false than the day test, short-circuiting the evaluation more efficiently.

Comment: How about: `Date.today.strftime("%m.%d").to_f.between?(12.1,12.25)` as alternative?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I like to keep it simple. A "clever" solution is easy to get wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If the date range is always going to be within the same month, you could convert the day element of the dates to integers and check if its within the range e.g.

```
(start_day.day..end_date.day).include?(today.day)
```